# Matrix Identity

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a  $ n \times n $ positive definite matrix, $P$ be a $n\times m$ real matrix with full column rank, I'm wondering whether we have the following inequalty
$$ P( P^{T} A P) ^{-1} P^{T} \preceq A ^{-1} ,$$
And in which sufficient conditions the the equality holds.

Comment: If $A$ is semi-positive, $A^{-1}$ might not be defined. Also, what do you mean by $\preceq$?

Comment: There are something wrong with your statement. First, $P$ has to be $n\times m$ real matrix. Second, $A$ should be positive defined. And @Martin, $A\preceq B$ means $B-A$ is semi-positive defined.

Comment: @wild Chan： Thanks for your pointing out the false in my statement！ I've corrected my question。

Comment: @mewmew I suppose that $P$ has to be column full rank, otherwise you cannot ensure $P^TAP$ is invertible.

Comment: @Wild Chan: You're right! P is column full rank.

Answer (score 3):

First we consider a easier version when $A=I$. We have to prove the matrix below is semi-positive defined:
$$I-P(P^TP)^{-1}P^T=I-PP^+$$
Here $P^+$ refers to [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse). Because $P$ is column full rank, we have $P^+=(P^TP)^{-1}P^T$.

A wellknown result for $PP^+$ is that it's an orthogonal projection onto $R(P)$, the range of $P$. We can prove it within three steps:

1. $PP^+$ is idempotent.
2. $PP^+$ is Hermite.
3. $R(PP^+)=R(P)$.

And then $I-PP^+$ is also an orthogonal projection, onto the $N(P^+)=\mathrm{Ker}P^+$. It is a simple deduction from those information that $I-PP^+$ is semi-positive defined, and it's $\mathbf{0}$ iff $\mathrm{rank}(P)=n$.

---

Now let's get to the general case. Because $A$ is positive defined, we have a invertible $n\times n$ matrix $Q$ so that $A=Q^TQ$. Notice
$$P(P^TQ^TQP)^{-1}P^T\preceq (Q^TQ)^{-1}\Leftrightarrow S(S^TS)^{-1}S^T\preceq I$$
where $S=QP$ is also full column rank. That's because pre-multiply by $Q$ and post-multiply by $Q^T$ cannot change the property of semi-positive defined. And now we can apply the result we've already obtained above.

The conclusion is: the inequality holds, and equality holds iff $\mathrm{rank}(P)=n$.